# Shortest code to split std::string into std::pair

Tags: c++, std

I have a text, in "key:value" format. The actual text may look like, `"Server: nginx"` or `"Server:nginx"` ignoring the whitespaces between the key, `:` and value.

What could be the fastest and shortest way to split this into a `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Not really, this is about pushing directly into the pair, much is about tokenizing

Comment: Requirements vastly underspecified, as discovered below. Please be clearer and more precise next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David was close, but he didn't actually test his code.

Here's a working version.

```
auto index = str.find(':');
std::pair<std::string,std::string> keyVal;
if (index != std::string::npos) {

   // Split around ':' character
   keyVal = std::make_pair(
      str.substr(0,index),
      str.substr(index+1)
   );

   // Trim any leading ' ' in the value part
   // (you may wish to add further conditions, such as '\t')
   while (!keyVal.second.empty() && keyVal.second.front() == ' ') {
      keyVal.second.erase(0,1);
   } 
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5ff3a538eeaf5b2))

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `stringstream` and use:

```
string str = "Server: nginx with more stuff";
std::string key, val;
std::stringstream ss(str);
std::getline(ss, key, ':');
std::getline(ss, val);
auto p = make_pair(key, val);
if (p.second.front() = ' ') // get rid of leading space if it exist
    p.second.erase(0, 1);
```

Comment: @xybrek: Pretty pointless link since we have no idea what your input data are

Comment: @xybrek This works with the sample data you included in your post.  If you have different constraints then you should add that to the question.

Comment: @xybrek and can you show how that should be parsed?  Does everything after `Response Headers:` need to be in value of that key?  Please edit your question with the relevant information.  It is not fair to ask for X and then comment that hey it doesn't work on Y which is actually what I want.

Comment: @xybrek So only the date one got cut. Maybe just replace `ss >> val` with another std::getline?

Comment: Yes, I'd do that. Getline with the default delimiter the second time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit using `getline()` again will still leave any leading whitespace in the second part.  I am trying to figure out a way to get rid of it.

Comment: Isn't there an istream manipulator to skip over any whitespace in the stream?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say

```
auto index = str.find(":");
std::pair<std::string,std::string> keyVal
if (index != std::string::npos){
 keyVal = std::make_pair( str.substr(0,str.size()-index),
 str.substr(index+1, std::string::npos));
 if (keyVal.second.front() == ' ') {keyVal.second.erase(0,1); } 
}
```

this will remove the whitespace if the seperator is ": " instead of ":"

of course , you can make the code spaggetier and remove even more line and use `str.find(":")` directly instead of 'index'.

Comment: missed that, one second .

Comment: @xybrek: Pretty pointless link since we have no idea what your input data are

Comment: @xybrek: You're right; this is broken. David it would be great if you actually _tried_ your proposed solution before handing it to the OP, instead of rushing to be the "frist"!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the usage of regular expressions (if the pattern of your values won't change at runtime):
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

But in concern of performance you should make speed tests for all the possibilities which are showed above (string parsing manually, using stringstreams, regular expressions,....

Comment: Why on earth would you use regular expressions for this?! The OP even specifically stated he wanted it to be fast....